# BaseFregment To be Parent of all the Child Fragments in my application?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-nested-fragment

I want to create an application in which I have a BaseFragment which is responsible for pushing and popping fragments in its container, actionbar click callbacks and navigation and all the child fragments extend BaseFragent.

How can i Do that?

`public abstract class BaseFragment extends fragment{}
public class ChildFragment extends BaseFragment{}`

can you tell me any example which implements code similar way??

Comment: after seeing your posted code one can easily say, yes all your child fragments will be of type BaseFragment !. can please elaborate little clearly your intentions with this design.

Comment: I just dont know how can i pass the childfragment view to parent as i want to put all the child fragments into the container of the parent fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do some thing like this:
**HomeActivity**

```
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    addFragments(new CategoryFragment(), true, false,
            AndyConstants.CATEGORY_FRAGMENT);
}

public void addFragments(Fragment fragment, boolean animate,
            boolean addToBackStack, String tag) {

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        if (animate) {
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right,
                    R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left,
                    R.anim.slide_out_right);
        }
        if (addToBackStack) {
            ft.addToBackStack(tag);
        }

        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag);
        ft.commit();
    }

}
```

**BaseFragment**

```
 public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment  {
    protected HomeActivity activity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activity = (HomeActivity) getActivity();

    }

}
```

**Your fragment**

```
     public class CategoryFragment extends BaseFragment implements OnItemClickListener  {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container,
                false);
        listView = (SwipeListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvCategory);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}




@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        SubCategoryFragment subCategoryFragment = new SubCategoryFragment();

        activity.addFragments(subCategoryFragment, true, true,
                AndyConstants.SUBCATEGORY_FRAGMENT);
    }

    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.. I just couldnt understand the categoryFragment Implementation :D ..  activity.addFragments(new Fragment(), true, true,
                        "Your tag"); wll  go into onCreateView? OnCreate() >??

Comment: Here i have called a method of addfragment in Homeactivity's oncreate method. now it will replace the Category fragment. now in the CategoryFragment you cat call method where you want to replace fragment some like onclick of some button or listviews's item click.

Answer (score 0):

Define a class which extends from android.app.fragment. In your child fragments you extend from this class.

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {}
```

`public class ExampleFragment extends BaseFragment {}`